# How do wait for AWS ECS Task to be in RUNNING state before moving to next step in AWS Step Function?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-ecs, aws-step-functions

I have an array of objects which I want to pass to a Lambda function iteratively. However, I also need to have an ECS Task running for each Lambda function I start.

I found that I would need to have an AWS Step Function where I iterate through an array of JSON inputs. For each input, I would have to start an ECS Task, wait for it to be in a RUNNING state, then move to next step where I invoke a Lambda function. In my case, the ECS Task itself does not return anything. It is supposed to stay running because the Lambda function uses it.

Currently, I have it so that the ECS Task starts but it stays stuck in the starting the ECS Task step because it does not return anything. How would I be able to wait for it be in a RUNNING state before moving to the next step?

Current Step Function definition:

```
{
  "StartAt": "Iterate",
  "States": {
    "Iterate": {
      "Type": "Map",
      "Iterator": {
        "StartAt": "Start ECS Task",
        "States": {
          "Start ECS Task": {
            "Type": "Task",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::ecs:runTask",
            "Parameters": {
              "LaunchType": "FARGATE",
              "Cluster": "<cluster-arn>",
              "TaskDefinition": "<task-definition-arn>",
              "NetworkConfiguration": {
                "AwsvpcConfiguration": {
                  "Subnets": [
                    "<subnet-id>"
                  ],
                  "AssignPublicIp": "ENABLED"
                }
              }
            },
            "Next": "Invoke Lambda function"
          },
          "Invoke Lambda function": {
            "Type": "Task",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::lambda:invoke",
            "Parameters": {
              "FunctionName": "<lambda-function-arn>",
              "Payload": {
                "Input.$": "$"
              }
            },
            "End": true
          }
        }
      },
      "End": true
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using an integrated AWS service (i.e. AWS Step Function), I created my own script for starting ECS Tasks using `aws-sdk` v3 for JavaScript. I specifically used the `waitUntilTasksRunning` function from the `@aws-sdk/client-ecs` package to wait for the ECS Task to be in a RUNNING state.

Read more about it from the documentation

- AWS SDK for JavaScript v3 : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/index.html
- @aws-sdk/client-ecs : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-ecs/index.html
- @aws-sdk/client-ecs waitUntilTasksRunning: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-ecs/globals.html#waituntiltasksrunning

Sample function for running and waiting for the ECS Task to be in a RUNNING state (TypeScript) note: not all parameters in the functions are required, check the documentation for that:

```js
import { ECSClient, RunTaskCommand, waitUntilTasksRunning } from '@aws-sdk/client-ecs'

const startAndWaitUntilECSTaskRunning = async (region: string, clusterARN: string, launchType: string, subnets: Array<string>, taskDefinition: string, securityGroups: Array<string>, assignPublicIp: string) => {
    var ecsClient = new ECSClient({ "region": region })
    var runTaskCommand = new RunTaskCommand({
        cluster: clusterARN,
        taskDefinition: taskDefinition,
        launchType: launchType,
        networkConfiguration: {
            awsvpcConfiguration: {
                assignPublicIp: assignPublicIp,
                subnets: subnets,
                securityGroups: securityGroups
            }
        }
    })
    var ecsTask = await ecsClient.send(runTaskCommand)
    var taskArn: string | undefined = ecsTask.tasks?.[0].taskArn
    if (typeof taskArn !== "string") {
        throw Error("Task ARN is not defined.")
    }
    var waitECSTask = await waitUntilTasksRunning({"client": ecsClient, "maxWaitTime": 600, "maxDelay": 1, "minDelay": 1}, {"cluster": clusterARN, "tasks": [taskArn]})
    // note: there are multiple waitECSTask states, check the documentation for more about that
    if (waitECSTask.state !== 'SUCCESS') {
        // your code to handle this
    } else {
        // your code to handle this
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

[ecs:runTask](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/connect-ecs.html) can be triggered in two different ways.

- arn:aws:states:::ecs:runTask.sync > runs and waits until task is completed
- arn:aws:states:::ecs:runTask.waitForTaskToken - triggers and wait until it receives a [SendTaskSucess or sendTaskFailure](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/connect-to-resource.html#connect-wait-token)

We need to use second method in this case,

Pass TASK_TOKEN as environment variable to ECS task and within ECS task first few lines of code, we need to send a SendTaskSucess.

Here is an example:

```
{
   "StartAt":"Run",
   "States":{
      "Run":{
         "End":true,
         "Type":"Task",
         "Resource":"arn:aws:states:::ecs:runTask.waitForTaskToken",
         "Parameters":{
            "Cluster":"arn:aws:ecs:us-east-1:620018741331:cluster/HelloCdkStack-ecstaskEc2ClusterB0EAAA1E-yPWjSYf8d03O",
            "TaskDefinition":"HelloCdkStackecstaskTD1950FF01",
            "Overrides":{
               "ContainerOverrides":[
                  {
                     "Name":"TheContainer",
                     "Environment":[
                        {
                           "Name":"TASK_TOKEN",
                           "Value.$":"$$.Task.Token"
                        }
                     ]
                  }
               ]
            },
            "LaunchType":"EC2"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: I was hoping to do it with just the AWS services because I didn't create the docker container (I pulled it for Docker hub) for the ECS Task so I am not sure how to edit it so that it sends a SendTaskSucess. Is this the only way to do it or is there another way that does not involve modifying the container?

Answer (score 0):

The AWS CLI has a convenience `aws ecs wait tasks-running` command. Some AWS SDKs offer a similar operation.  The [documentation](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/ecs/wait/tasks-running.html) for this command states:

> Wait until JMESPath query tasks[].lastStatus returns RUNNING for all elements when polling with `describe-tasks`. It will poll every 6 seconds until a successful state has been reached. This will exit with a return code of 255 after 100 failed checks

In other words, the "wait" operation is just simple polling behavior built atop the [ECS DescribeTasks](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/APIReference/API_DescribeTasks.html) API action.

You can implement this same polling behavior natively in a AWS Step Function.  A [Wait state](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-wait-state.html), followed by an [AWS SDK integration state](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/supported-services-awssdk.html) to invoke the ECS DescribeTasks action, and then a [Choice state](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-choice-state.html) to evaluate the `lastStatus` value and proceed to appropriate next states (e.g. "running", "failed", or back to the wait state.)

The visual Workflow Studio designer makes it pretty easy to define this kind of polling pattern. One potential benefit of a native Step Function solution is fewer AWS resources to manage (you don't need to define a Lambda function to implementing the polling). A potential downside is cost. The current [AWS Step Function pricing](https://aws.amazon.com/step-functions/pricing/) for standard workflows is based on state transitions, so this approach could be expensive (depending on volume), as each polling loop involves transitions of "wait", "describe", and "choice" states. Express workflows could be a better option here, provided your workflow runs in less than 5 minutes.